# Update Pattern, exit and remove

Tags: d3.js

I have a stackblits [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/d3-start-above-zero-erhfjn?embed=1&file=index.js&hideNavigation=1). I'm trying to create a simple example using the D3 update pattern. Clicking the update button randomly selects from the data and updates the graph. This is happening but it's putting the new graph on top of the current graph and not removing current graph.

I'm using `exit()` `remove()` but obviously not correctly.

Comment: actually the example is not working as you described in the question.

Comment: Sorry, it should now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your biggest problem is that you are creating new scales & axes on each update, whereas you should just be feeding the scales the updated data via their respective domains and calling them again on each axis.

Also, while you *are* positioning new bars on `.enter` (x, y, width & height attrs), you are doing nothing to the old bars that should `.update`. So you also have to position those previously existing bars (or else bars appear to overlap each other).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="chart-container"></div>
  <button id="btn">Update</button>
  <script>
    var originalData = [{
        "date": "Jan",
        "value": 1507
      },
      {
        "date": "Feb",
        "value": 1600
      },
      {
        "date": "Mar",
        "value": 1281
      },
      {
        "date": "Apr",
        "value": 1898
      },
      {
        "date": "May",
        "value": 1749
      },
      {
        "date": "June",
        "value": 1270
      },
      {
        "date": "July",
        "value": 1712
      },
      {
        "date": "Aug",
        "value": 1270
      },
      {
        "date": "Sept",
        "value": 1257
      },
      {
        "date": "Oct",
        "value": 1257
      },
      {
        "date": "Nov",
        "value": 1277
      },
      {
        "date": "Dec",
        "value": 1057
      }
    ];

    ///////////////////////////// Update function

    function randomizeData(data) {
      var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length) + 2
      var newData = data.slice(0, rand);
      update(newData)
      console.log(newData)
    }

    ///////////////////////////// Create SVG

    var w = 400;
    var h = 250;

    var margin = {
      top: 20,
      bottom: 40,
      left: 40,
      right: 20
    }

    var width = w - margin.left - margin.right
    var height = h - margin.top - margin.bottom

    var svg = d3.select(".chart-container").append("svg")
      .attr("id", "svg")
      .attr("width", w)
      .attr("height", h)

    var chart = svg.append('g')
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var x = d3.scaleBand()
      .range([0, width])
      .padding(0.1)


    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .rangeRound([height, 0])


    var xAxis = chart.append('g')
    var yAxis = chart.append('g')

    ///////////////////////////////// Update function

    function update(graphData) {

      // Recalc domains based on new data
      x.domain(graphData.map(function(d) {
        return d.date
      }));

      y.domain([0, d3.max(graphData, function(d) {
        return d.value;
      })]);

      // Redraw axes based on new data
      xAxis.call(d3.axisBottom(x)).attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      yAxis.call(d3.axisLeft(y))

      var u = chart.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(graphData);

      // Enter
      u.enter()
        .append("rect")
        .classed('bar', true)
        .attr('x', function(d) {
          return x(d.date)
        })
        .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
        .attr("y", function(d, i) {
          return y(d.value);
        })
        .attr("height", function(d, i) {
          return height - y(d.value);
        });

      // Update
      u.attr('x', function(d) {
          return x(d.date)
        })
        .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
        .attr("y", function(d, i) {
          return y(d.value);
        })
        .attr("height", function(d, i) {
          return height - y(d.value);
        });

      // Exit
      u.exit()
        .remove();
    }

    randomizeData(originalData);

    var button = document.getElementById('btn');
    button.addEventListener('click', () => randomizeData(originalData));
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

[stackblitz fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/d3-start-above-zero-rqkyqk?file=index.js)

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the X,Y scales and axes out of update function and use `remove()` `exit()` inside the update.

```
///////////////////////////// Update function

function doUpdate(gdata){
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*data.length)+2
    var newData = data.slice(0, rand);
     update(newData)
}

///////////////////////////// Create SVG

var w = 400;
var h = 250;

var margin = {
  top: 20,
  bottom: 40,
  left: 40,
  right: 20
}

var width = w - margin.left - margin.right
var height = h - margin.top - margin.bottom

var svg = d3.select(".chart-container").append("svg")
  .attr("id", "svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h)

var chart = svg.append('g')
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([0, width])
  .padding(0.1)
  .domain(data.map(function(d) { 
    return d.date
  }));

  var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0])
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { 
      return d.value; 
    })]);

var xAxis = chart.append('g')
    .classed('x-axis', true)
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x))

  var yAxis = chart.append('g')
    .classed('y-axis', true)
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y))   

///////////////////////////////// Update function

function update(graphData){
  console.log(graphData,graphData.length)
  var u = chart.selectAll(".bar")
    .remove()
    .exit()
    .data(graphData);

    u.enter()
     .append("rect")
     .classed('bar', true)
     .attr('x', function(d){
      return x(d.date)
    })
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("y", function (d, i) {
      return y(d.value);
    })
    .attr("height", function(d,i){
      return height - y(d.value);
    });



}    
var button = document.getElementById('btn');
button.addEventListener('click', doUpdate);
doUpdate(data);
```

Comment: This kind of works, but does nothing about updating the axes.